# Different tickers with the same ISIN are the same - even if stock price is different?

Tags: equities, finance

I'm a little confused about this. Say there's a ticker I'm interested in called `A` ("Company Holding AG") @ \$1.2. I search for `A` and "Company Holding AG" on my broker and find ticker `B` also called "Company Holding AG". It's currently at \$1, not \$1.2.

Now I find ticker `A.C` and `D` which are both ("Company Holding AG") on two different exchanges, which have both `A.C` and `D` listed, at different prices than that of `B` that my broker has. Prices between all of these are different, even taking into account any currency conversions that are involved.

I take the ISIN from ticker `B` on my broker and put it through OpenFIGI, which returns me a list containing `A, B, A.C, D, E` all called "Company Holding AG", all with the same share class.

What happens if I buy `B`? Am I buying "Company Holding AG" (`A, A.C, D, E`) which **happens** to be called `B` *on my broker* or am I buying something completely different than what I originally wanted to buy, `A`? If `D` goes up, do `A, B, A.C, E` also all go up since they're all "Company Holding AG"? Does them having the same ISIN and same share class mean they're all the same security just traded under different names or are these 5 all totally different securities?

Comment: Can you check the share class?

Comment: Look for examples of Royal Dutch Shell A and B.

Comment: @wecandothis the share class for all are the same

Comment: Can you please give a specific example? Usually, an ISIN identifies a specific instrument, e.g. ordinary shares or preferred shares for a company. For example, in Germany, BMW.DE and BMW3.DE are ordinary and preferred equity of Bayerische Motorenwerke Aktiengesellschaft.